# Azure App Service Plan - Importance of location selection

Tags: azure, location, price, azure-app-service-plans

why app service plan price vary depending on location. If i create a app service plan for CentralUS and create all resources for Japan East location then what will happen. Any impact on performance.

I know azure keep metadada in selected location...any other reason.

=====added=========

**If an app service plan is created for CentralUS then azure internally create a set of compute resources for that plan in that region.
Now if new resources "Sql Server", "Sql Database" is create for "Japan-East" location then these resources will be created in "Japan-East" region. And this will cause data traffic between these two location- is my understanding is correct.
If this is correct then related resources should be created in same location as a best practices.**

==================

Thanks,

@paul

Comment: Most important reason is data traffic _within the same region_ does not incur costs, while traffic _between different regions_ is seen as outgoing data, which does incur costs. So there's that.
You can also imagine that using resources across regions/datacenters/countries will be less performant than using them from the same datacenter.

Comment: Thanks @rickvdbosch, so if we plan to deploy an web app in two different location the we should have separate web service plan for each location. If we have only one App service plan(CentralUS) and create two resource group one for "CentralUS" and another for "Japan East" it will not perform well..is it correct?

Comment: @paulsim - resource groups really have no relevance; they are just organizational constructs (along with access policies). Doesn't matter what resource group you put something in, nor does it matter where the resource group's region is. You just have to worry about where your app and related services run. You can scatter them across the globe, but as Rick pointed out, you'll deal with bandwidth costs (along with latency).